# Joomla control view and layout with php

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I was sitting for hours now searching the net however couldn't find an answer to my problem

I am using Joomla with Virtuemart 2.

For some pages I need to make a different style and I use the following code:

```
<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='reset') { ?>

//HTML
<?php
}
?>
```

This works perfectly as long no "layout" is included in the link.

As soon the link looks like "/index.php/component/users/?view=reset&layout=confirm" my HTML changes are not valid any more.

I would need something like 
`<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='reset'&&('layout')=='confirm') { ?>`

It would be also enough if I could code something like "When view includes reset then"

I hope you can help me out.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The reset view of the users component has three different layouts:

- default
- complete
- confirm

I'm not sure how you are overriding the layout, but I assume you are changing the default code and not the confirm code.

To override these, you should copy the .php files from components/com_users/views/reset/tmpl to templates/yourtemplate/html/com_users/reset/

Note that you should never edit core files - always use an override.

Comment: If this doesn't help, update your question to say where you are putting your code.

Comment: it seems like I missed the forest for the trees. I was trying so many things but did not check there are more files in this view to be edited. Thank you. You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

The flowing code:

```
<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='reset'&&('layout')=='confirm') { ?>
```

Needs to be corrected to:

```
<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='reset' && JRequest::getVar('layout')=='confirm') { ?>
```

If you need to catch an empty variable you could use:

```
<?php if (empty(JRequest::getVar('view'))) { ?>
```

Or if you want to make sure that a variable exist:

```
<?php if (!empty(JRequest::getVar('view'))) { ?>
```